# Which type of stats test to run when comparing vendor data sets against target data set

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, linear-regression, regression-testing

My boss asked me to compare web click data between an ad server we subscribe to and the demand-side platform and see how those compare to Google Analytics sessions. The concern is that the ad server is overcounting clicks while the ad server says the demand-side platform is undercounting clicks. I was able to join the datasets from our ad server, demand-side platform and Google Analytics based on partner name. There were only 13 joins. I was looking to see what's the best way to determine the accuracy between the two data sets and Google, with Google being the target variable and the vendors as predictor variables. Is this a linear regression via Pearson coefficient?

Comment: Can you explain this question further? Shouldn't the numbers be exactly the same from different sources?

Comment: We have 13 different sources (in this sample, I've asked for a larger one) that drives different amounts of traffic to a website. Some ads drive more traffic than others. The ad server and demand-side platform reported different amounts of clicks and impressions in each instance. We are trying to determine if the ad server or demand-side platform is more closely aligned to google analytics sessions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of statistical tests that determine if distributions are significantly different. You could take a look at the t-test: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html

Or the Mann-Whitney U test: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html

If the number of observations is particularly small, or if you believe that the distributions are normally distributed then you can use the t-test. Else, try the Mann-Whitney U test.